# JDBC CallableStatement issue

Tags: java, jdbc

please help me to fix a problem. I need to print the NAME of a user , but get only first letter of it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {            
    Connection conn = null;
    java.sql.CallableStatement stmt = null;     

        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);       

            String sql = "{call retrieveFirstName(?,?)}";
            stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);

            //Bind IN parameter first, then bind OUT parameter
            int uID = 1;
            ((java.sql.CallableStatement)stmt).setInt(1,uID);
            ((java.sql.CallableStatement)stmt).registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

            ((java.sql.CallableStatement)stmt).execute();

              //Retrieve employee name with getXXX method
            String userName = ((java.sql.CallableStatement)stmt).getNString(2);
            System.out.println("User Name with ID:" + uID + " is " + userName);         

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            //close resources
        }
}
```

Here is a procedure

```sql
create procedure retrieveFirstName
@userID int,
@firstName varchar(250) output
as
begin 
select @firstName=first_name
from user_account
where id=@userID
end
```

Comment: Your java code seems to be fine. I think the problem is with your stored procedure. Can you confirm the procedure's output using Sql client?

Comment: You don't need to cast to (java.sql.CallableStatement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify the out parameter as

```
((java.sql.CallableStatement)stmt).registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
```

without specifying the precision of the VARCHAR.

Please try specifying the precision as third argument to registerOutParameter.